# How to access a label from a thread in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, label

I have tried to access a label via

```
label.Text = "Some Text";
```

from a thread. But i cant be accessed.
I cant define the label as public, because its inside the Windows Forms system ish. For an example Form1.cs is the class with all the program, and in the other tab is there Form1.css[Design].

So.

How can i access the label in Form1.css[Design] from the Form1.css.

PS: I'm still a beginner in C#.

This is all the code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BatteryAnalyser
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread batteryThread = new Thread(BatteryStatusThread);
    int toogle = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }


    static int GetBatteryStatus() // THIS PART WORKS TO GET THE STATUS OF THE BATTERY
    {
        int batteryStatusValue;
        PowerStatus p = SystemInformation.PowerStatus;
        batteryStatusValue = (int)(p.BatteryLifePercent * 100);
        Debug.WriteLine("Get Battery Status Method called. Battery percentage = " + batteryStatusValue);
        return batteryStatusValue;
    } // GOOD CODE WORKS



    public static void BatteryStatusThread() //THIS IS THE THREAD THAT SHOULD UPDATE THE BATTERY PERCENTAGE IN THE LABEL VIA labelBattery.Text
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BatteryThread entered");


        while (true)
        {
            int batteryVal = GetBatteryStatus();

            labelBattery.Text = batteryVal.ToString(); //THIS PART DOSNT RESPOND


            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }





    private void calculatingToogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(toogle.ToString());

        labelBattery.Text = "It works from here because its a non static method";

        if (toogle == 0)
        {
            toogle = 1;
            calculatingToogle.Text = "Stop";

            try
            {
                batteryThread.Start();
                //Debug.WriteLine("Thread.Start activated");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Battery Thread start " + e.ToString());
            }

            try
            {
                batteryThread.Resume();
                //Debug.WriteLine("Thread.Resume activated");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Battery Thread Resume " + e.ToString());
            }
            return;
        }


        else if (toogle == 1) ;
        {
            toogle = 0;
            calculatingToogle.Text = "Start";

            try
            {
                batteryThread.Suspend();
                //Debug.WriteLine("Thread.Suspend activated");
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Battery Thread Suspend " + e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I found out that i cant change the label because its a static thread. But in the non-static method it works fine. How do i solve that?

Comment: Look at the links in the Related column at right.

Comment: You _should not_ be accessing WinForms controls from another thread.  The design is fundamentally flawed.  How to check if you're on the right thread? Use  `Control.InvokeRequired`.  You can marshal over with `Control.BeginInvoke` and `Control.Invoke`, among many other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the file name is Form1.css? If so, you are working in a Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) file. In the CSS file, you modify the style of your form and its elements. If you are working in Visual Studio, IntelliSense will not prompt you with your form control names in a style sheet.

If you have a form named Form1.cs[Design], the code behind will be in Form1.cs. If you are using Visual Studio, you can enter 'F7' or right click on your form and '<> View Code' to open this file.

In this file, you will be able to access the controls you added to your form in Form1.cs[Design]:

```
`namespace YourWindowsFormsApplication
 {
     public partial class Form1 : Form
     { 
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.Text = "Some Text";
     }
 }`
```

UPDATE:

Because BatteryStatusThread() is a static method, you need to create an instance of your Form:

```
public static void BatteryStatusThread() //THIS IS THE THREAD THAT SHOULD UPDATE THE BATTERY PERCENTAGE IN THE LABEL VIA labelBattery.Text
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("BatteryThread entered");


        while (true)
        {
            int batteryVal = GetBatteryStatus();

            Form1 form = new Form1(); //Create instance here

            form.labelBattery.Text = batteryVal.ToString(); 

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thats what im doing. But in a another thread in the same class.

Comment: Can you post an image of your solution explorer and/or your code?

Comment: I have posted it now

Comment: I have tried now and it didnt work. If a create a new instance of the form it dosn't call the labelBattery, but a copy inside the new instance. That is at least what i think it did. But thanks for helping Jason!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to the label in the static method parameter:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        StaticMethod(this.label1);

    }

    static private void StaticMethod(Label TheLabel)
    {
        TheLabel.Text = "This is from a static method";
    }
```